# PHP & MYSQL password_verify issue

Tags: php, mysql, hash

Basically. I am having a problem decrypting my passwords.This is for a dummy project and is done in mysql (I understand it is now depreciated, I am learning mysqli & PDO currently).

I can hash the password perfectly, like so:

```
$password = password_hash("$password1", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $password = substr( $hash, 0, 60 );
```

My database password field is set to `CHAR(255)` so I am stumped.. currently I have password_verify running like so:

```
// Define $username and $password
   if (isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"]=="login") 
   {
    $username =$_POST["username"];
    $password =$_POST["password"];

// SQL query to fetch information of registered users and finds user match.
//searches table for a username and password matching post data 
    $dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username';";
    $dbResult = mysql_query($dbQuery);
    $dbRow=mysql_fetch_array($dbResult);

    $username = $dbRow["username"];

// checks if user exists from sql
    if(mysql_num_rows($dbResult)==0)
    {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Oops! No user exists under that username!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }

    $hash = $dbRow['password'];
    // checks if password matches stored hash

    if (password_verify('$password', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
}
   }
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Surely your second `echo 'Password is valid!';` should be `echo 'Password is not valid!';`

Comment: Also, you have the single-quoted string `'$password'` when what you want is the variable `$password`

Comment: @IMSoP Yes, sorry it did say Not Valid, I had the hash in there so I could see if the password was being retrieved from the table okay and copied and pasted without thinking. I have tried the password with and without ' but nothing..

Comment: Wait, what's this line doing there? `$password = substr( $hash, 0, 60 );` You can't trim down a hash, it will no longer be the same hash.

Comment: @IMSoP I put this in because I had read somewhere that I needed to limit the size of it, even if i remove this line there's still no luck